# How to create a onepage wordpress site menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a onepage wordpress theme. I use static front page for onepage sections. When I go out home page I cant come back to home page. I use links like `#about-us` on home page and how to add site url before link like `www.example.com#about-us`. Please give me a jQuery solution.
I tried but homepage is refreshing.
This is my code:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').not('.navbar-nav li.current-menu-item a').each(function(){
    var menuAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
    var newMenuAnchor = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>' + menuAnchor;
    if (( menuAnchor.indexOf('#') > -1 ) ) {
        $(this).attr("href", newMenuAnchor);
    }
});
```

Comment: How does your menu looks like? Did you try anything to do with jquery? How do we know what to use if there is not a single piece of code written?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I updated the code.

Comment: Where did you put this code? Because if it's just in your .js file, then php inside won't work.

Comment: I use this code in my footer.php file.